# How to save Iterable[String] to hdfs in spark-scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

```
val ordersRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/orders");
val ordersRDDStatus = ordersRDD.map( rec => (rec.split(",")(3), 1));
val countOrdersStatus = ordersRDDStatus.countByKey();
val output = countOrdersStatus.map(input => input._1 + "\t" + input._2);
```

How to save output which is Iterable[String] to hdfs in spark-scala. 
Iterable[String]

Note: ouput is not an RDD (I cannot use output.saveAsTextFile("hdfs-path")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to just write a simple HDFS file (same way you would do in vanilla Scala or Java). This has nothing to do with Spark.

Another way is to convert your `output` to an RDD and save that.

```
val output = countOrdersStatus.map(input => input._1 + "\t" + input._2)
sc.makeRDD(output.toList).saveAsTextFile("hdfs-path")
```